Kafka Producer test sink postgres connector
I want to test kafka producer on postgresql database :
create table test (id derial primary key, value text)

I insert on kafka producer, this value
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic postgresql.public.test
{"id":1, "value":"aa"}

but I get this error:
org.apache.kafka.konnect.errors.DataException: JsonConverter with shemas.enable requires schema and mayload fields
